# How can I plot a vector-valued function?

Tags: plotting

I have a vector

$\qquad R(t) = (-5t^{2} + 4)\,\hat{i} + (4t - 1)\,\hat{j}$

which can be written

```
R[t_] := {-5t^2 + 4, 4t - 1}
```

in Mathematica. How can I plot that in just one $xy$-plot?

I have searched in Implicit Functions of Mathematica, but I have found nothing that works for my purpose.

Comment: Look up study and the examples of [`ParametricPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot.html) and review the syntax of vectors (a.k.a. `List`) ([this guide](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/OperationsOnVectors.html) is one starting point).

Comment: BTW, I call your sort of function a *parametrized curve*, a *parametrization*,  or a *vector-valued function of a single variable*.  An [implicit function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function) is something else.

Comment: `ParametricPlot`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
R[t_] := {-5 t^2 + 4, 4 t - 1}
ParametricPlot[R[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image: plot]